# Prioritizing scan results using multiple weighted attributes in a math algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, expression, formula, weighted

I would like to ask a math expert for advice about a work project I have.  I have software that scans computer file systems for certain faults.  It's similar to a vulnerability scanner.  Each fault detected is assigned a severity ranking on a 5-point scale (5 being highest priority) by the software.  Thousands of faults are usually detected, and I need to prioritize which ones to give attention to.  But I can't trust only the severity ranking from the scanner, because there are other attributes that can increase or decrease the overall severity of a fault that cannot be programmed into the scanner (some attributes are manually assessed or come from different scanners).  Let's say there are four of these external attributes: attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, each with its own ranking.  att1 and attr2 use a 5-point scale for ranking of 1/info, 2/low, 3/med, 4/high, 5/urgent.  attr3 uses a 3-point scale of low/med/high, and attr4 is a yes or no.  I am trying to create a metric for fix-priority based on a 10-point scale, with 10 being the most urgent, based on the scanner ranking and also the external attributes.   My thinking is that, for a fault to receive a fix-priority=10, each attr would need to be assessed at its max value and also the scanner ranking would need to be at its max value.  Any attr or scanner ranking less than maximum would cause fix-priority to decrease to a number lower than 10.

My formula is this:

( ( (scannerRank*0.2)+(attr1*0.2)+(attr2*0.2)+(attr3*0.33)+(attr4*0.5) ) / 4.99 ) * 10

It seems to work.  But here is my question:  attr4 uses a simple yes or no metric, so each of its values, 1 or 2, is worth 0.5 in my calculation.  Similarly, attr3 has 3 possible values, each worth 0.33.   So, are attr3 and attr4 getting more weight and importance in the calculation compared to attr1,attr2 and scannerRank?   If so, how should I handle this, because I view each attr as equally important when determining fix-priority.   Also, in the future, if I change my mind about an attr and view it as being more or less important than another attr, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: Imho better places to ask this question are [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would assign each attribute a value between 0 and 1 by doing (attr - minAttr) / (maxAttr - minAttr), e.g. (attr1 - 1) / 4. Then you can sum them up, divide by the total number of attributes and multiply by 10. Like this everything is weighted equally.

Comment: @MrT: thank you, I did not know about those forums.  Will see what replies I get here.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. T.  You are right, this is better addressed on the Math forum.  For anyone interested to know, I did post there too and the question was answered well.  [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690828/prioritizing-results-using-multiple-weighted-attributes-in-a-formula)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to separate the belief or uncertainty part of this problem from the assessment or cost or loss or preference part. That is, separate what you think is going on from how much you should worry about it. Then combine the belief with the assessment via expected value of the assessment, and make the decision which minimizes the expected assessment (assuming that assessments are negative values).

This is a Bayesian decision theoretic approach. It is conceptually simple and very general. "Making Hard Decisions" by Robert Clemen is a good introduction.